# How can i draw a black point on the 0,0,-1 opengl coordinate of the screen?

Tags: android, opengl-es

actually I'm drawing a cube, I'm checking rotation problems of the cube, but for this I need to draw a point on the 0,0,-1 opengl coordinate of the screen, I'm using perspective projection, MyGLSurfaceView and android 1.5 opengl es 1.x

How can I draw a black or white point on the 0,0,-1 opengl coordinate of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to draw directly in window space then the easiest thing would be to load modelview and projection temporarily with the identity matrix and draw a `GL_POINT` with the location that you need. So that'd be something like:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

// draw the point here; specifics depending on whether you
// favour VBOs, VBAs, etc

// e.g. (assuming you don't have any client state enabled
// on entry and don't care about leaving the vertex array
// enabled on exit)
GLfloat vertexLocation[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f};

glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexLocation);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

// end of example to plot a GL_POINT

glPopMatrix();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();

// and possibly restore yourself to some other matrix mode
// if, atypically, the rest of your code doesn't assume modelview
```

Comment: i dont know how to draw the point at 0,0,-1, please can you add the code for do it?

Comment: I've added some code but on re-reading your question I think I may have misunderstood what you were asking. Do you want (0, 0, -1) to be the position in your 3d world, which would be affected if you have a camera and it moved, or do you want it to be directly in eye space?

Comment: GLfloat doesn't exit's on android :S what i should use?

Comment: I just want to draw a point on the 0,0,-1 opengl coordinate. Just that

Comment: @AndroidUser99 Tommy's question is, **what is an "opengl coordinate"**? Is it a screen coordinate in pixels, a normalized device coordinate in post-projective space, a world-space coordinate, a view-space coordinate or an object-space coordinate? Yes, I used all these terms to make you look up their meaning and get a better grip of OpenGL's transformation pipeline.